# router::url doesn't work in the same controller

Tags: cakephp, router

I have this form:

```
<div id="buscador">
        <form action="<?php echo Router::url(array('controller'=>'categorias','action'=>'buscar'));?>" name="form_search" id="form_search"  method="post"  >
            <input type="text" name="search">
            <input type="submit" value="Buscar" class="buscador" id="boton_buscar"/>
        </form>
</div>
```

It works fine in all controllers except when you are using the controller "categorias"... in that case, the result is this: http....Categorias/buscar/Buscar
Any idea why this happens?

Comment: It appears you're in a View, not a Controller.  So use this instead: `$this->Html->url(array('controller'=>'categorias', 'action'=>'buscar'));`  That being said, I think you're leaving something out.  It seems strange that it would capitalize "Categorias" - or was that just a typo?  Also, why not use the FormHelper?

Comment: Nope, that produces exactly the same result. and the capitalization is no mistake.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was present elsewhere, I didn't consider that when clicking the button inside the View "buscar", then JS acts on that click (and this generates the buscar/Buscar problem)